# Convert float and maintain decimal places

Tags: javascript, floating-point

I have this values:

```
var a = 20.0;

document.write(a);                  --> 20
document.write(a.toFixed(2));       --> "20.00"
```

I want to know if its possible to maintain the decimal places and the variable as float?

Something like this:

```
20.00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kind of floating point numbers used by JavaScript (IEEE-754) don't maintain a "precision" value of that kind (e.g., something to say that "`20.00`" has two zeroes after the decimal, but "`20.000`" has three). Trailing zeroes after the decimal point are not significant.

There is a style of number for doing that in some environments (Java has `BigDecimal`, C# has `decimal`), but nothing built into JavaScript does. I believe there's a `BigDecimal` port to JavaScript out there.

Answer (score 2):

A `.0` portion of a number is irrelevant to its value.

Just convert it as you need to when it's time to show the end user.